# Objective-C: What is the difference between creating an object from alloc/init and class method calls?

Tags: objective-c

For example,

1. ```
   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:@"a string"];
   ```
2. ```
   NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"a string"];
   ```

and while we're talking about strings, is there any difference by setting up a string with:

```
    NSString *string = @"a string";
```

?

As a final note, this isn't a specific question about NSString. I'm asking on a wider scope of all NSObjects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in ARC, but prior to it there was a difference: `alloc/init` returns an item with ref count of at least one that you'd need to `release` when you don't need it, while the class method returns an autoreleased item that you'd need to `retain` if you would like to keep it. The ARC compiler knows all this, and takes care of retaining/releasing for you based on your ownership specifications.

Comment: oh what would i do without arc